# End of statement expected. - VB Code to WebService Error

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I'm getting this error when trying to debug my VB code in Visual Studio to interact with a specific WebService .
Im not very familiar with Visual Basic.
The error is on the line `Dim ticket_handle As String = " CR 1001 " ws.closeTicket ( Sid , " closed ticket " ticket_handle )`
The complete code:

```
Imports System.IO Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports WebReference
Partial Class _Default

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim ws As New USD_WebService
Dim sid As String
Dim userhandle, username, password As String
Dim attrVal(5), attr(0), prop(0) As String
Dim requestHandle, requestNumber As String
Dim persistent_id As String
Dim catAttrib(5) As String
Sub Main()
    Dim ws As New USD_WebService
    ws.Url = "http://hummer:8080/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService?wsdl"
    Dim username, password
    Dim sid
    username = "servicedesk"
    password = "password"
    sid = ws.login(username, password)

    Dim userhandle
    userhandle = ws.getHandleForUserid(sid, username)

    Dim USD As New WebReference.USD_WebService
    sid = USD.login(username, password)
    Dim ticket_handle As String = “cr:1001” ws.closeTicket(Sid,“ticket fechado”, ticket_handle)

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ws.Url = "http://hummer:8080/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService?wsdl"

End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone help me plis?!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET, only one statement may be executed per line. Other languages, like Java or C# use a ';' to denote the end of a statement, however in VB.NET it is the end of a line. The compiler is trying to tell you that you have two statements on a single line and it expects there to only be one.

```
Dim ticket_handle As String = “cr:1001” ws.closeTicket(Sid,“ticket fechado”, ticket_handle)
```

Should be

```
Dim ticket_handle As String = “cr:1001” 
ws.closeTicket(Sid,“ticket fechado”, ticket_handle)
```

Comment: You can have more than one statement per line in VB if you use the 'line join' character - a colon.